# scribus interface do not scale correctly on ubuntu budgie 18.04

Tags: display, qt, budgie, appimage, scribus

I just installed ubuntu budgie 18.04 on my new computer. I installed the set of tools that I use on my linux workstations including krita (via appimage), blender (with the files from blender.org), kdenlive (via appimage) and scribus-ng (via ppa).

I have a problem with scribus and krita: the buttons, menus, icons, ... are huge and pixelized. But the text is at a standard size. Both program are unusable without correction.

For krita I went in the configuration file and remove hidpi support (there is such an option). Now it works like a charm. But for scribus there is no such option. I tried to launch it with QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.6 and it is still barely usable as the text decrease too.

I though that it would be a problem with Qt, but it seems not, as kdenlive worked perfectly out of the box. Still, with appimage it's hard to be sure.

Is there some option I'm missing somewhere ? Could it be that my screen (HP compaq la2405wg) is sending misleading hidpi informations ?

Comment: I installed mate just to see if it could be related to budgie and apparently it is, because on mate I have no problems (but the de is not as nice :S).

Comment: And after installing mate, but logging in budgie, if I launch scribus from the command line or via a desktop fiel I wrote and click onto in the file explorer it works correctly. But If I lauch it from the menu or budgie's dock (even the same desktop file), then it appear way toooo big.

Answer (score 0):

With Debian testing it works OK with the latest Scribus code.

The problem seems to be solved with the most current (available) versions of Qt and Scribus.

I would not suggest you to install newer versions of Qt than what Ubuntu provides, but you could try to install `scribus-trunk` instead of `scribus-ng`. There might have been some progress on this matter since the release of Scribus 1.5.4.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it didn't work. I think my screen might also be part of the problem by providing some false informations on HiDPI support. I also tried scribus appimage but the issue is still there.

Comment: of course, you should setup everything correctly and then remove the scale factor.

Comment: in the "preferences > user interface", you can also set the text size for the menues and the palettes. as said, i have a scribus that is mostly ok... so it must be possible to get there : - )

Comment: Yes, I know, but the text already have the correct scale, and if I increase it it leads to other problems. It's not a problem with scribus, but with budgie, as it is solved but only if I open mate, then close it, then open budgie.